# What's the difference between those statements?

Tags: java, numbers, ieee-754, floating

These days, I'm working on some problems regarding [ACM-ICPC](http://icpc.baylor.edu/) (although I already graduated.. just for fun..). Yesterday, I nearly became crazy because there is an online judge which always said "WRONG ANSWER" to code I'd written. And finally after more than horrible 10 hours, I realized that a following statement was the reason.

```
   int target = (int)((double)(M * 100) / N) + 1;          // RIGHT!!
   int target = (int)((double) M / N * 100) + 1;            // WRONG!!
```

I couldn't exactly know how and why the first statement behaves differently from the second one. Because I'm not allowed to see test cases which are used by the judge, it's a little hard for me to understand when the code can go wrong. Is there anybody who can explain to me? Thank you.

* I'm using Java.

Comment: What are the types of M and N?

Comment: What do you mean by wrong , do you get an error or is it giving a different answer explain? Also what is the datatype of M and N.

Comment: @Valentin Oh, I missed it. The type of M and N is long.

Comment: @user699617 I submitted my code and the online judge said 'wrong code'.. Usuaully, the judge put some input and check whether the right outputs come from my code (He doesn't explain anything about WHY it is wrong.. He just said 'wrong'). But because of the UGLY code, output went wrong than was expected by the judge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the result of these two expressions

```
(double)(M * 100) / N
(double) M / N * 100
```

is the same EXCEPT for floating point precision errors (and also for possible overflows, but let us ignore them here since both lines are susceptible to them, albeit in a different way). These errors COULD cause the values to be one slightly above or equal to an integer, and one slightly below the same integer, which would cause

```
(int)((double)(M * 100) / N)
(int)((double) M / N * 100)
```

to differ by one. In general, when dealing with floating point, you have more chances to get closer to the "real" value if you leave the division as the last operation.

There is one further consideration, which can get quite tricky: you have no parentheses around `(double)M/N` in your second line. This MIGHT give additional freedom to an optimizer, which could make the result dependent on the optimization level. I don't know whether this can happen in Java.

As for the order of operations, I tried out this particular case in C (because that's quicker for me):

```
int i, j, k;
for (i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
   j = (int)(((double)i / 100) * 100);
   if (i != j) {
      printf("%d -> %d\n", i, j);
   }
   k = (int)(((double)i * 100) / 100);
   if (i != k) {
      printf("%d ?? %d\n", i, k);
   }
}
```

and the output on my machine is

```
29 -> 28
57 -> 56
58 -> 57
```

Replacing 100 with 10000000 yields 587200 lines of the same kind (i.e., an error rate of 5.872%)

Comment: I appreciate your explanation. I should try to leave floating number operations as the last operations. But... sorry, I have one more question. When I was an undergraduate, professor ever said that Fortran can gaurantte accuracy of floating number operation. But yesterday somebody argued that is totally wrong. He said that Fortan also uses IEEE 754 as the other programming languages, and the primitive floating number operations (except wrapper something like BigDecial in Java) in EVERYWHERE must be inaccurate. What do you think about his saying? Again, thank you and sorry for interrupting you.

Comment: @gwpark, the guy you talked to is correct, although some operations have total accuracy with some inputs, like, e.g., `*` and `/` with powers of 2, or `*` of two integers whose total number of digits is less than the significant digits of a floating point number (most probably as in your case for `M * 100`). But you started with a wrong statement, because, e.g., `(double)(M * 100) / N` and `(double)M * 100 / N` have an integer `*` the first and an FP `*` the second, but practically always yield the same result - it's not having the `/` last that can give a different result